# How to Implement Controllers Inherited from ControllerBase in Library-Type Assemblies?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm working with C# ASP.NET Core 6 and facing a challenge in implementing controllers inherited from ControllerBase in assemblies of the "library" type. Previously, it was possible to load packages like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` version 2.2.5 or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` version 2.2.8. This automatically added a controller when adding a NuGet package containing it to an API. However, these packages are now considered obsolete. Additionally, the same NuGet package version 6.0.0 isn't available for download from NuGet because it's now included in the standard ASP.NET Core package. But this isn't suitable for my use case as I am working with a class library.

How can I make controllers, inherited from ControllerBase, work in a class library with ASP.NET Core 6, considering the unavailability and obsoleteness of the aforementioned packages? Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` version 2.2.8 is deprecated.
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions` version 6.0.0 doesn't work.
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core version` 6.0.0 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue of outdated libraries, I manually included the following tag in my .csproj file: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="6.0.0" />`. Although this cannot be downloaded directly from NuGet, adding it manually proved to be effective. However, this approach is not ideal. It allowed me to pass the internal security department's review, but it greatly restricts the functionality of the library I created.